# Center Wordpress Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've looked at similar questions and can't find a solution:
I have a Wordpress page and the menu is left-aligned, but I'd like it to be centered.
I've tried adding `margin: auto;` and `text-align: center;` to various elements but no joy.

https://test.mintrain.co.uk

Any help would be great.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.main-navigation ul { 
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
.main-navigation ul { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, helped a lot, I needed to add 'text-align: centre' to .main-navigation as well to get it working